# Taking the average of a sliced list

Tags: python, list, sum, moving-average

The problem I'm having is attempting to take the average of my list (derived from y, which is a list of sin values). However, when running the code, I get the error

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'

Any help you could offer would be greatly appreciated

```
for k in range(len(y)-1-r):

    list_to_avg = [y[r+k:len(y)-1-r+k]]
    b =float(sum(list_to_avg, []))
    a =float(len(list_to_avg))
    z.append(b/a)
```

Comment: helpful also to provide example *inputs*. Please take the [tour] and read [ask] for tips on improving the quality of this question. As currently asked, it's not very good.

Comment: Can't tell for sure without more info but I believe your error is on this line `list_to_avg = [y[r+k:len(y)-1-r+k]]`. Try removing the outer square brackets. You're getting a list of lists as it's currently written. It would also help to print intermediate variables when debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
b = float(sum(list_to_avg, []))
```

to this:

```
b = float(sum(list_to_avg))
```

You are asking `sum` to add an empty list (`[]`) to whatever the contents of `list_to_avg` are.

---

Since line `b = float(sum(list_to_avg, []))` is not throwing:

> TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "*whatever<sup>1</sup>*") to list

it means that `list_to_avg` is a list of lists. I cannot know whether that is intentional or not so I assume it is. But if it is, the result of the summation would also be a `list` which of course cannot be cast to `float` and thus the:

> TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'

---

<sup>1</sup>The *whatever* is mine. For example if you had `sum([1, 2, 3], [])` it would say `TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list`

Answer (score 0):

You have made `list_to_avg` a list that contains a list.

Use

```
list_to_avg = y[r+k:len(y)-1-r+k]
```

instead.